# What is the best Wiki solution for Django?

Tags: django, integration, wiki, wiki-engine

I am not aware of a really good Django-App which provides Wiki functionality.
There is http://code.google.com/p/django-wikiapp/ , but it is not that extensive and no activity anymore.

Any pointers of how to integrate an already proven (and known) Wiki to Django?

Comment: Hi @loomi, I'm also looking for a good wiki application for Django, it really appears that actually there isn't too much choice. Do you have any news about this? What's the result of your research? Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Though not strictly answering to your question, [cmsplugin-markup-tracwiki](https://bitbucket.org/mitar/cmsplugin-markup-tracwiki/overview) might be a solution. I don't know how good it is, but at least it seems maintained.

Comment: Hi, this look's interesting indeed. But trac brings me already too much functionality. I did look into Dokuwiki integration for now. I wrote a authentication module for DokuWiki which authenticates against the django user database. http://www.dokuwiki.org/auth:django (imports even the groups)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki. I've installed it and so far it looks very promising.

Comment: There is no documentation on how to actually get started using this project. :(

Comment: @rjurney There is - but you are also most welcome to help improving it: https://django-wiki.readthedocs.io/en/main/index.html

Answer (score 6):

One of these many packages may suit your needs: [Djangopackages.com wiki grid](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/wikis/)

[www.djangopackages.com](http://www.djangopackages.com/) is a great resource for looking for apps.

Comment: Thank's this is a great resource! Unfortunately it doesn't help me in my decision of how to integrate a working and fullfeatured Wiki in Django. (There are a lot small projects but non of them is promising enough to adapt.) I think I will most probably integrate a PHP based Wiki like a Mediawiki or Dokuwiki.